# The meaning of "a little Moor and how much it is"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, literature

> The Duke of Falvertoon was one of those human *hors d'oeuvres* that
>   stimulate the public appetite for sensation without giving it much to
>   feed on. As a mere child he had been precociously brilliant; he had
>   declined the editorship of the *Anglian Review* at an age when most boys
>   are content to have declined mensa, a table, and though he could not
>   claim to have originated the Futurist movement in literature, his
>   "Letters to a possible Grandson," written at the age of fourteen, had
>   attracted considerable notice. In later days his brilliancy had been
>   less conspicuously displayed. During a debate in the House of Lords on
>   affairs in Morocco, at a moment when that country, for the fifth time
>   in seven years, had brought half Europe to the verge of war, he had
>   interpolated the remark "**a little Moor and how much it is**," but in
>   spite of the encouraging reception accorded to this one political
>   utterance he was never tempted to a further display in that direction.
>   It began to be generally understood that he did not intend to
>   supplement his numerous town and country residences by living overmuch
>   in the public eye.

from [East of the Web](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/UnkiBlow802.shtml)

Why did the Duke of Falvertoon say "a little Moor and how much it is,"?

Comment: It’s a pun but I don’t understand the thrust. It’s a play on the fact that *Moors* (a type of people) are found in Morocco, and the couplet starting “a little more and how much it is” from the Robert Browning poem *By The Fire-side*:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294443/the-little-more-and-how-much-it-is-the-little-less-and-what-worlds-away . Maybe the joke is Morocco is Moorish and little, but despite its littleness, it is “much”, having brought half Europe to the brink of war multiple times. “It’s little and Moorish and yet we’ve had much ado about it”.

Comment: What **I** want to know is *what is with that random “a table” after “mensa”*???

Comment: @Dan Bron - _mensa_ is Latin for "table", and was usually the first noun encountered by British children who were taught Latin at school, as I was starting in 1963. _Mensa, mensa, mensam_. To know _mensa_ is not to know very much Latin. Mensa, a table; liber, a book; arbor, a tree.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Oh! *Declined* “mensa” the Latin noun, as in inflect it for number of gender or whatever. Not “decline Mensa”, “refuse an invitation to join the high IQ society”. That’s how I’d originally read it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. As you have gathered, Saki is being witty about the two meanings of 'decline'. Declined an editorship when most boys his age were content to decline _mensa_.

Comment: @Dan: It's obviously *both* (his peers would be satisfied to have mastered Latin declension *and* turned down an invitation to Mensa). I thought that was far wittier than the "little Moor" pun.

Comment: Munro/Saki isn't saying that. Mensa didn't exist in 1914 anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: In this post-modern age, I have no problem finding something "witty" even if the aspect that I find cleverest *today* couldn't possibly have been known to the original writer. But ty for the info anyway - until I just looked it up, I assumed Mensa was much older, and that Saki *would* have known what he was writing.

Comment: If the Duke had declined to join that bunch of twats, had it existed then, Munro would surely have capitalised its name.

Comment: If only to avoid the Latin-lesson interpretation (the one he actually intended).

Answer (score 3):

As people have noted in the comments, the Duke of Falvertoon is making a pun based on a misquotation of what was then probably a much better known quotation of a poem by Robert Browning. The poem is "By The Fire-Side" and can be read in full [here](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/by-the-fire-side/)

The orginal line by Browning is:

> Oh, the little more, and how much it is!

Browning's original implication, [as stated here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294443/the-little-more-and-how-much-it-is-the-little-less-and-what-worlds-away), was to suggest that the final small step of fully loving someone ('the little more') makes a very large difference.

The joke depends on the fact that the words 'more' and 'Moor' are homophones. ('Moor' was then still a commonly used word to refer to any African in the English-speaking world.)

In essence Falvertoon, who never usually bothered to speak in parliament, and never did again, is making a literary in-joke about how Morocco, a small African nation, can bring the great powers of Europe to the brink of war.

The joke today, if it were not so obscure as to evade easy comprehension, would be considered in poor taste at best.